# 2点間の距離の求め方　エラーは"invalid syntax"です

Tags: python

二点(cos pi/3, sin pi/3) と(-exp(2), log(10))
の距離を求めるために以下のようなコードを書きました。

```
import math

def distance(x1,y1,x2,y2):
  return ((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)**0.5

print(distance(( math.cos ( math.pi / 3 ))., ( math.sin ( math.pi / 3 ))., ( -math.exp(2))., ( math.log(10)).)
```

するとエラーに“invalid syntax”と出てきてうまくプリントされませんでした。

mathを使った4つの値をそれぞれprintで表示させてみると上手く計算されたのでその部分のミスではないと思います。

どこを修正すればうまくコードが動くのか教えていただけませんでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

これは単に各パラメータの最後に`.`が付いているのが余計であることと、最後の`)`が不足しているからでしょう。

以下のようにすれば動作するでしょう。

```
print(distance(( math.cos ( math.pi / 3 )), ( math.sin ( math.pi / 3 )), ( -math.exp(2)), ( math.log(10))))
```